# Network Configurations of VMs

Tags: virtualization

I have installed 2 VM's on my Windows 7 machine: Backtrack (kali) and Metasploitable.

When I run a nmap scan on metasploitable from metasploitable VM itself, it shows that 3306 port is open.

But when I run the scan from Kali all ports show closed. Also when both are in NAT network configuration, their IP is the same.

Is this some issue with the network adaptors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I figured it out. I am using VirtualBox but this solution will work for VMWare also.

First, before opening any VM's, go to File>Preferences (this will bring up the VirtualBox Preferences) and select network. Click the Add New NAT button on the right. Here you need to specify the default gateway. I used 192.168.0.0. Click OK then open up your VM's.

My two machines are now 192.168.0.4 & 192.168.0.5 when at first they were both 10.0.2.15. This was resulting in the closed ports like you say because the Kali machine was Nmapping itself! Now it properly scans Metasploitable 2.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can change your network settings in VMware or Virtual machine, don't know which one you use, so those VM's are able to find each other.

You should set up a DHCP on the VM Emulator so you don't have to worry about network settings.

You can do it manually as well:

Check if the network is up anyway?

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Check on kali:

```
sudo ifconig

  inet Adresse:192.168.1.120  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
```

Now check on theother VM:

```
sudo ifconfig 
  inet Adresse:192.168.1.121  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
```

They should be on the same network.

You can set the network settings like so:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.121 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

For more information check out the `man ifconfig`.

If this all fails try the nmap `-PN` switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16947/discussion-between-vivek-and-aul5agoi).